# Using wildcard SSL certs (chain certificate) with mod_gnutls

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have a wildcard SSL certificate from GoDaddy that has three files:

wildcard.crt
gd_bundle.crt
wildcard.key

In setting up mod_gnutls to be used with Apache, I can get the site to come up, but it throws a warning that the SSL certificate has not been validated by a CA.

When I use mod_ssl, I can stipulate a SSLCertificateChainFile directive and point it at the bd_bundle.crt file. I do not see how to do this with mod_gnutls.

Any help is appreciated. I also know that mod_ssl supports SNI, so if there is not an easy answer, I will just try that.

Thanks,

QWade

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the chain certificate file at the end of your regular certificate file, it works under most implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I often prefer to update ca-bundle.crt, which is referenced system wide by anything compiled against OpenSSL.

In CentOS, this is stored in `/usr/share/ssl/certs`.  This can differ between distributions.